# Android Begineer: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-intent

I am new to android/java so please bear with me. My code was working fine earlier, but ever since I added the for() loops, I have been getting a NullPointerException. Any Ideas?

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends Activity {

SharedPreferences settings;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
static CheckBox box, box2;

private final static CheckBox[] boxes={box, box2};
private final static String[] checkValues={"checked1", "checked2"};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    box=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    box2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

    settings= getSharedPreferences("MyBoxes", 0);
    editor = settings.edit();

    if(settings != null){

    for(int i =0;i<boxes.length; i++)
        boxes[i].setChecked(settings.getBoolean(checkValues[i], false));   
    }

}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
   super.onStop();

   for(int i = 0; i <boxes.length; i++){           
   boolean checkBoxValue = boxes[i].isChecked();        
   editor.putBoolean(checkValues[i], checkBoxValue);
   editor.commit();       
   }

    }
}
```

Comment: logcat trace please , I think that boxes are null on your for statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialise the values of `box` and `box2` to be `null` (as this is the default value when they are not assigned explicitly).  These values are then used when creating your `Checkbox` array `boxes`.  Thus, `boxes` has two null values.  You then reassign the values of `box` and `box2`.  Note that this has no effect on the values within the `boxes` array.  Thus when you attempt to access the values within the array you get a `NullPointerException`.

Set the values within `boxes` *after* you have assigned values for `box` and `box2`.

Comment: can you give an example of how I would do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fixed code. Hope it help:

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends Activity {

    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    static CheckBox box, box2; // box and box2 are null when class is loaded to DalvikVM

    private final static CheckBox[] boxes={null, null};
    private final static String[] checkValues={"checked1", "checked2"};


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        box=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        box2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

        // assign CheckBox instances to boxes array
        boxes[0] = box;
        boxes[1] = box2;

        settings= getSharedPreferences("MyBoxes", 0);
        editor = settings.edit();

        if(settings != null){

        for(int i =0;i<boxes.length; i++)
            boxes[i].setChecked(settings.getBoolean(checkValues[i], false));   
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        for(int i = 0; i <boxes.length; i++){           
            boolean checkBoxValue = boxes[i].isChecked();        
            editor.putBoolean(checkValues[i], checkBoxValue);
            editor.commit();       
        }
    }
}
```